# The eigenspaces of $f : A \in M_2(K) \mapsto A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $V= M_2(K)$ and consider the linear map $f:V \rightarrow V$ where $f(A)=A^T$ (the transpose of $A$).

I am task with finding the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenspaces of $f$. The eigenvalues are $-1$ and $1$ as they are the roots of the minimal polynomial. In the solutions, I am given the following answer to the eigenspace. *I do not understand it at all*.

\begin{align*}V_1 &= \mathrm{Span}\{E_{1,1}, E_{2,2}, E_{1,2} + E_{2,1}\}\\ V_2 &= \mathrm{Span}\{E_{1,2} - E_{2,1}\}\end{align*}

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What did you not understand, exactly? It's quite hard to provide an adequate comment or answer based solely on "I have no clue" or "I don't understand". Telling us what you have tried or understood, even if you failed overall, lets both you and us know what or where the problem is. As an aside, images are usually frowned upon unless necessary due to a part of the userbase using screen readers, as well as images being an obstacle to searchability in general.

Comment: I believe $E_{i,j}$ is the matrix where the $(i,j)$-th entry is $1$ and all other entires are $0$.

Comment: in other words $V_1$ is the subspace of symmetric matrices and $V_2$ is the subspace of skew-symmetric matrices.  It is strange that your problem tells you $\mathbb K$ is algebraically closed as such information is irrelevant for an involution; telling you $\text{char }\mathbb K\neq 2$ is relevant though.

Comment: @BrunoB I do not understand why $V_1$ and$ V_2$ are the span of their respective bases

Comment: @Justauser Thank you for that clarification. Are you able to explain why the span of *those* specific bases are used?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is an eigenvector of $f$ for eigenvalue $1$, then by definition $f(A)=A^t=A$. That is, $A$ is symmetric. It's easy to check that all of $E_{1,1}, E_{2,2}, E_{1,2}+E_{2,1}$ are symmetric. Therefore $V_1$ is an eigenspace of $f$ for eigenvalue $1$.

Similarly, we have the eigenvectors of $f$ for eigenvalue $-1$ are precisely the skew-symmetric matrices, and it's easy to see that $E_{1,2}-E_{2,1}$ is such a matrix, hence $V_2$ is an eigenspace of $f$ for eigenvalue $-1$.

If the characteristic of $K$ is not $2$, then it's easy to see that all of the above matrices are linearly independent. And $\dim(V_1+V_2)=\dim(V_1\oplus V_2)=\dim(V_1)+\dim(V_2)=4=\dim M_2(K)$. Therefore $V_1\oplus V_2=M_2(K)$, hence we know there are no other linearly independent eigenvectors. In particular, $V_1$ (resp. $V_2$) is exactly the eigenspace for eigenvalue $1$ (resp. $-1$).

That is, as long as the characteristic of $K$ is not $2$, $f$ has eigenspace decomposition, and there is no need for $K$ to be algebraically closed.

This can also be seen by the fact that any matrix $A$ can be decomposed as the sum of a symmetric and a skew-symmetric one as $A=\frac{A+A^t}{2}+\frac{A-A^t}{2}$.

Yet another way is to see that $f^2=I$, and $f\not=I$, hence the minimal polynomial of $f$ is $x^2-1$ that has no repeated roots when $\operatorname{Char} K\not=2$, hence must be diagonalizable. What if $\operatorname{Char} K = 2$? By the same argument, the minimal polynomial of $f$ has repeated roots, hence it cannot be diagonalized, but it has a generalized eigenvector such as $E_{1,2}$. Again being algebraically closed is not needed for the decomposition.